# Dev mode vs production mode in React Native (Xcode)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

**Memory errors when testing on physical iPhone**

I currently am experiencing memory issues when I run my react-native app on a physical device (iPhone connected through USB cable). I have tracked it down to too many console.log outputs. I have come across a couple of different solutions:

1. On this [React-Native page][1] Facebook recommends using the `babel-plugin-transform-remove-console`  plugin. It is to be installed to work in dev mode only `npm i babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save-dev` with the following code in .babelrc:

   {
   "env": {
   "production": {
   "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
   }
   }
   }

Note: I do not have a `.babelrc` file. I only have a `babel.config.js` file.

2. Some people are recommending using:

   if (!**DEV**) {
   console.log = () => {};
   }

I believe this is setting any instance of console.log to an empty object if you are not in DEV mode.

**Issues with getting accepted at the App Store**

Apple is rejecting my app due to a bug at the point this memory error is happening. So, I am assuming that the console.log() statements are being compiled with the app and that they are encountering the memory error as well. They have not told me that there is a memory error, but just that it is not working at that particular point.

**DEV mode vs Production mode**

With options 1 and 2 above both assume a production mode vs a dev mode. However, when I compile the app with Xcode to upload to the App Store, how do I know what mode it is going to be in?

When I select Product>Archive from Xcode does that automatically put it in Production mode instead of Dev mode? Or is there something else I am needing to do to ensure that it is compiling it in production mode?

Comment: How did you figure that your memory issues came from too many logs? I'm wondering cause I've worked on big apps with lots of logs and never had memory issues coming from that, even without using the solutions you mentioned (eg. the babel plugin, etc). Just a though.. anwyays, let me know if my post answers your question✌️

Comment: @colakollektiv When I commented out the console.log there was no memory issues, when I uncommented them there was. Some of the outputs were several pages of json data. But if that shouldn't be an issue then I'm not sure what else was going on.

Comment: Ok. I am using this solution in one of my apps now `if (!DEV) { console.log = () => {}; }` I wasn't having memory issues, but security issues (logs were showing on production builds on Android with `adb logcat`). I guess if you wanna be sure your logs are removed in prod you can try building a release apk for android and run `adb logcat`, then look for your logs - they shouldnt be there.

Comment: adding maybe unrelated case, my `console.log` get stuck when i try to log `ref` object such as `console.log({ref})`. everything is ok when i comment those logs

Answer (score 1):

When you archive your app in Xcode it will be in "PROD" mode (aka release mode). In Xcode you can run your app in both DEV (aka debug mode) and PROD in Xcode. That will make it easier for you to get to the bottom of this memory issue.
To do this:

**1. select the scheme you're working with in the top bar, click "Edit scheme"**

[image]

**2. and then set "Build configuration" to Release, and uncheck "Debug executable"**

[image]

You can select any Simulator or connected device press the "Play" button to run a release build, with all the performance optimizations that come with that.

Comment: So, when you `archive` using XCode does it use the info in your configuration files for compiling? Such as babel.config.js, package.json, etc.?

Comment: tbh I dont remember ever having to handle that myself, but im sure React Native is doing a lot in the background. You can take a look a this for a little more details: https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/publishing-to-app-store

Answer (score 0):

what you have after doing archiving is a production code.

And in my cases, my production app got stuck when it stumbles to a code which logging a `React.createRef()` object. In dev mode everything is ok.

You may try using `if(__DEV__){...}` to log anything, as all those `console.log` **still fire** in production